# How to get title of preferencescreen on Android

Tags: android

I am trying to gate the title of preferencesreen in my program.. How can I get the title?

My code of preference XML is here. I want to get the title "Show List" in my program.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Settings">
        <PreferenceScreen android:title="Show List" android:key ="show_list" android.id="@+id/preference_screen">
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
                android:targetPackage="com.picknext"
                android:targetClass="com.picknext.PickName" />
        </PreferenceScreen>
        <ListPreference android:title="Remove after pick"
            android:key="selection_of_Y_N_Name_Pick" android:entries="@array/selection_of_y_n_namepick"
            android:entryValues="@array/value_of_y_n_naempick" android:defaultValue="Yes" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a class that extends PreferenceActivity. Inside this (for example in onCreate()) you have a call to addPreferencesFromResource(). After this you have access to the title via the methods getTitle() and setTitle().

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanx for yo reply buddy but for this method i can get only the main title of preferencescreen and i want to get the title of inner preferencescreen titled by "Show List" in ma program..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "inner title" but I guess you mean Summary? there are methods setSummary() and getSummary() for that.